# Format doesn't work when concatenating 2 fields into another

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a table called tblSource that contains a "Month of Birth" field and a "Date of Birth" field. These are formatted as Numbers - 00, for example March would be 03. These appear fine in that table.

Now what I'm trying to do is concatenate these values into a field in the second table tblTarget called DOB. Its format is MMDD, represented as 0000, so the 3rd of March should appear as 0303. This is where I'm having the problem - the DOB for 3rd March is actually appearing as 0033.

Here is the SQL in the query I'm using:

```
INSERT INTO tblTarget ( [NABP-ePID], DOB )
SELECT tblSource .[NABP e-profile ID], tblSource .[Month of Birth] & tblSource .[Day of Birth] AS DOB
FROM tblSource 
WHERE tblSource .[Certification Type]='Pharmacist' Or tblSource .[Certification Type]='Pharmacy Technician';
```

Is the format of the target table (0000) the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem - the problem lay in the fact that if you specify a field as a number it will cut off any preceding zeros as they aren't necessary.

For example 03 would be represented as 3 so when you concatenate 03 (March) to 03 (Third day) you would get 33. If the format of the target field is 0000 - you are basically providing some padding - therefore 33 would appear as 0033.

Hope this helps others.